# SQL One to Many Relationship in a Dashboard

Tags: sql, looker-studio

Not sure if this is the right way to phrase the question but I have a database shown below

```
ProductA   ProgramA
ProductB   ProgramB
ProductC   ProgramBoth
```

One issue I'm facing is when I put this into a dashboard and I use the dashboard to filter only ProgramA, I want to see both Product A and Product C. And when I filter ProgramB, I would like to see both Product B and Product C. Technically the user can select two of the programs in the dashboard drop down ("ProgramA + ProgramBoth), but they don't.

Am I pushing the limits of SQL? Is there a way around? As a note, I'm importing this from a Google Sheet, so I can change the underlying values if that's easier. In Google Sheets, I have a dropdown so only one value can be put in at a time (can be changed).

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing the limits of SQL :-)
What you are describing is a many-to-many relationship, and instead of thinking about a relationship of "both", think about it as a row for each relationship so for product C you will have 2 rows - one for program A and one for program B, something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Programs
(
 Product VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES Products(Product),
 Program VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES Programs(Program),
 PRIMARY KEY (Product, Program)
);

INSERT INTO Product_Programs (Product, Program)
VALUES ('ProductA', 'ProgramA'),
       ('ProductB', 'ProgramB'),
       ('ProductC', 'ProgramA'),
       ('ProductC', 'ProgramB');
```

Now you can easily query for any product participating in a program with

```
SELECT Product
FROM   Product_Programs
WHERE  Program = 'ProgramA';
```

Which will return both product A and product C.

HTH

Comment: I was thinking about the same solution, but there are two issues I see. 1) how would I use sql to create another row? Some sort of join? 2) If the filter on the dashboard doesn't select anything, it will show duplicate products.

Comment: the queries that the application uses are not part of the data representation. I'm not sure what you mean by 'some sort of join', but you simply insert 2 rows. the products, programs, and the relationships are 3 distinct entities. you would first insert all products, then all programs, and lastly a row for each relationship. To avoid duplicates, use either SELECT DISTINCT, or select from products directly where there is one row per product, and if needed, use EXISTS to filter only products that have relationships.